# Printing out the letter appears the most

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
   FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
   int c;
   int most;
   int count[256];
   if (fp==NULL){
      printf("Error: %s does not exist\n",argv[1]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   for(c=0; c<256; c++){
      count[c]=0;
   }

  while(c=fgetc(fp)){
    tolower(c);
    int i;
    if('a' <=c&& c<='z')
        count[c-'a']++;
    for(int i = 0; i<256;i++){
        if(count[i]>count[most]){
            most=i;
        }
    }
 }

    printf("Most frequent letter is '%c', it appeared %d times.\n",most+'a',count[most]);

 fclose(fp);
}
```

ok I'm suppose to create a c program that reads a txt file from the command line and output which letter appears the most and how often does it appear. I don't know how to fix my code. When I run it not happens.

Comment: "it not happens." So what does happen?

Comment: `most` is used whilst uninitialised. This and other issues in your code can easily be spotted by using a debugger to trace the program execution.

Comment: never access anything beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter actually exists

Comment: this code block `for(c=0; c<256; c++){
      count[c]=0;
   }
` can be eliminated by declaring the array `count[]` via:  `int count[256] = {0};`

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
tolower(c);
```

doesn't do anything useful in your program. You need to capture its return value.

```
c = tolower(c);
```

In addition, the `for` loop to compute the index of the most frequently occurring letter needs to be moved out of the `while` loop.

```
while((c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF ) // Note the update to this line
{
   c = tolower(c);
   if('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
   {
      count[c-'a']++;
   }
}

most = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<256;i++)
{
   if(count[i]>count[most])
   {
      most=i;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The posted code contains several undesirable elements,

1. misconceptions about the number of characters in the alphabet,
2. lots of unnecessary traversing of the array `count[]`,
3. using the contents of uninitialized variables,
4. lacks organization,
5. passes error messages (which may be incorrect) to stdout rather than stderr,
6. includes a header file those contents are not used,
7. and much more

The following code cleanly compiles and implements the desired functionality:

```
#include<stdio.h>  // fgetc(), fprint(), printf() fopen(), fclose()
#include<stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include<ctype.h>  // tolower()

#define MAX_ALPHABET (26)

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    if( argc < 2 )
    { // then no command line argument
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <fileNameToRead>\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, command line argument exists

    FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");   
    if (!fp)
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    int c;
    int count[ MAX_ALPHABET ] = {0};

    while( EOF != (c=fgetc(fp)) )
    {
        c = tolower(c);
        if('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
        {
            count[c-'a']++;
        }
    }

    size_t most = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<MAX_ALPHABET; i++)
    {
        if(count[i] > count[most])
        {
            most = i;
        }
    }


    printf("Most frequent letter is '%c', it appeared %d times.\n", (char)(most+'a'), count[most]);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

With the above code in a file named `untitled.c`  here is the command line:

```
./untitled untitled.c
```

and here is the output:

```
Most frequent letter is 'e', it appeared 123 times.
```

Comment: You can do `if( count[c - 'a'] > count[most] ) most = c - 'a';` inside `if('a' <= c && c <= 'z')` and remove the `for()`.

Comment: @MayurK, Your correct, however, I was trying to make the code as clear as possible, not as short as possible.